# Hadoop Mapper parameters meaning

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I am new to Hadoop and have a question about the parameters:
for the word count example, see below code snippet:

```
public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

   .....

   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
   {
       .......
   }
}
```

I know the "value" parameter is the line read from file, but what does the "key" parameter mean? what does it correspond to?

Why it's type is LongWritable?

I wasted several hours on it by searching the doc, could anyone help?

Comment: The input  keys and values used depend entirely on the InputFormat, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is of type `LongWritable` because the wordcount program takes the input as `TextInputFormat`

As per [JavDoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) for `TextInputFormat`

> An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines.
>   Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line.
>   **Keys are the position in the file**, and values are the line of text..

By definition suppose your text is

```
We are fine.
How are you?
All are fine.
```

Then Input to the mapper is

Key: `1` Value:`We are fine.`

Key: `14` Value:`How are you?` (There are approx 13 characters in first line including newline, so line position is 14)

Key:`28` Value:`All are fine.` (There are approx 13 more characters in second line including newline, so line position since start of the file is 28)